# Error Call to a member function posts() on null

Tags: laravel-8

Please i need help, am trying to create post for user and everything was working well until i tried to auth the user to show that the post belongs to a logged in user but am getting this error. please which other way can i check for a logged in user? fine my code below:

PostController:

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'title'=> 'required',
        'description' =>'required',
        'image'=>'required|image',
    ]);
    
    auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

}
```

Web:

```
Route::post('/p', [PostController::class, 'store']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try with**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $validator = request()->validate([
        'title'=> 'required',
        'description' =>'required',
        'image'=>'required|image',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()->withError('Validation error.');  
    }

    Post::create($request->all()+['user_id' => auth()->user()->id]);
    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Successfully added.');
}
```

**Post** is your model name, so include post model into controller file like use Post; .

**user_id** define store login user id. So you can change according to your database.

Error and Success have 2variable. The variable name get into view blade **{{ $error}}** & **{{ $success }}**

Comment: Thank you very much. please am getting this error on the page: ErrorException
Attempt to read property "id" on null
http://127.0.0.1:8000/p

Comment: Share the screen shot.

Please use DD for debug, to find out the login user details.
dd(auth()->user());
then check response and get the login user id and pass into create function.

Answer (score 0):

[Determining If The Current User Is Authenticated](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated)

> To determine if the user making the incoming HTTP request is
> authenticated, you may use the `check` method on the `Auth` facade.
> This method will return `true` if the user is authenticated:

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
    auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
} else {
    throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```